# Opencv2.4 compiling error on ubuntu during installation

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, cmake, vision

I'm new with opencv.I'm trying to install opencv24using the script and with out it (manually building everything) and everything I get the same error even though it says done; it doesn't do anything. Could you help me? Thanks

```
**[ 33%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/system.cpp.o
/home/pc/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/system.cpp: In function ‘(static initializers for /home/pc/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/system.cpp)’:
/home/pc/OpenCV/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/system.cpp:280:10: error: inconsistent operand constraints in an ‘asm’
         );
          ^
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/system.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2**
sudo: checkinstall: command not found
OpenCV 2.4.10 ready to be used
```

Comment: I would recommend going for [openCV  3.0](http://opencv.org/opencv-3-0-alpha.html) which is newer version identical to OpenCV2 almost completely but is faster mostly. Is this the [script](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV) your'e refferring to that doesn't work? If it's not try that that has always worked for me. Do read the text as well since it gives important information as well. Also which ubuntu are we talking about here?

Comment: I am running the script that is on this site https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV

Comment: I ran the script, and I also have done everything without the script, and it still gives me the same error. I am running Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. Thank you. 
@ljetibo
http://stackoverflow.com/users/2809008/ljetibo

Comment: Are you building as root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Read this bug report](http://code.opencv.org/issues/3983) It seems to report having the same type of error. Apparently old gcc compilers have an issue with some asembly code.

```
**/home/ubuntu/opencv/opencv-2.4.10/modules/core/src/system.cpp:280:10: error: inconsistent operand constraints in an ‘asm’
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/system.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2**
```

Could you do a `gcc --version` If it's something around 4.7, 4.8 That's ok. If it's not, although I would find that strange, could you do a

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get build-essentials checkinstall
```

Like Aidana Kane recommended. You could be using old package lists, and could easily get `no new software installed\updated` `up to date` etc report. If even after you've done the `sudo apt-get update` it still doesn't work, try installing `gcc-4.8` explicitly.

I would recommend that solution, updating to newer gcc, rather than monkeypathching the files. However, the bug has been reported fixed in OpenCV version 2.4.11 so you could try and get that one from the git repo. Or even something "more drastic" as making sure you edit your file `system.cpp` to look **exactly** like [this](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/commit/ea50be0529c248961e1b66293f8a9e4b807294a6) one.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion of editing the file, it worked. Thank you everybody for your answers. They all were very helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/users/2809008/ljetibo

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have checkinstall installed :)

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
```

Comment: I have it, it still give me the same error. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. I'd take a look at @ljetibo's suggestion - they seem to know a bit more about this specific lib.